# Should I put my UserDefaults saving process into ViewModel? (good architecture)

Tags: swift, mvvm, architecture, rx-swift

I'm creating a simple NewsApp. I want to create the best app architecture I can made. So my question is that if I want save really simple data like username and maybe 5-6 tags as strings, should I put userDefaults logic into my viewModel or should I create a layer between ViewModel and UserDefaultsAPI which will take care about saving data?

I mean I will create StoreData protocol which UserDefaultsAPI will implement. And if I should do it how I can achieve that? I am using RxSwift and I don't now how to subscribe changing data in UserDefaults by UserDefaultsAPI.

Comment: Putting it into a separate class/struct would make it easier to replace with another storage solution.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Ok, so I created something like that:
- I created UserDeafultsAPI wich is implementation of DataService protocol (saveData() and getData()) and only that class know about UserDeafults

- and I created UsetSettingsStorage wich is singleton wich is implementation of StorageService, and that singleton store all user settings and that viewModel wich need access into settings observe that singleton variables via RxSwift. And every time when somone change singleton values he is always save new values by DataService

is that ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a layer between, but given an Rx/functional architecture, it shouldn't be something heavy weight like a protocol.

Learn [How to Control the World](https://vimeo.com/291588126) and do something like this instead:

```
struct Storage {
    static var shared = Storage()
    var saveProperty: (Property) -> Void = { property in
        UserDefaults.standard.set(try? JSONEncoder().encode(property), forKey: "property")
    }
    var deleteProperty: () -> Void = {
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "property")
    }
    var currentProperty: () -> Observable<Property?> = {
        UserDefaults.standard.rx.observe(Data.self, "property")
            .map { $0.flatMap { try? JSONDecoder().decode(Property.self, from: $0) } }
            .distinctUntilChanged()
    }
}

struct Property: Codable, Equatable { }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I think it can be good way, but unfortunately I don't how to use. Could you show me very simple example of it? I watched movie you linked but still I am not sure how to do that

Comment: The above *is* a simple example of it.

Comment: Sorry, I am just dumb. Everything is clear. Thanks a lot for your help! Have a nice day! :) But if I can I have one more question is it nesesery to keep my data encoded?

Comment: It is not. If you have simple data that UserDefaults already supports, you don't need to worry about the encoder/decoder.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what your doing creating a seperate layer gives you, the opportunity to have different sources for data that implement the same protocol could be useful, and your data may be complex types than need to be encoded and decoded, so it makes sense to encapsulate that out, you may also want to provide some limit range to some of your values, but UserDefaults is just a service like NotificationCenter, you are not going to automatically wrap NotificationCenter in ever class, just do what is simplest, but doesn't run the risk of painting yourself in a corner later on. You are not going to get every issue decided at the get go right, the skill is to make sure you can quickly change if the need arises, and knowing about what possibility's you will need to take advantage of in the future and how can you avoid needing to make complex changes in the moment that don't add squat. There are lots of things you need to do, and being able to prioritise them is an important part of what you do, don't try make cleaver designs, be cleaver in making designs that can be easy for other to understand and modify.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I really appreciate that. What you said makes sense for me. Have a nice day!